# android boot - where is the init.%hardware%.rc read in init.c ? where are services started?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, boot, init, android-kernel

Going through the code in [`init.c`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/system/core/init/init.c#962) and trying to figure out 2 things:

- Where is the hardware specific init.%hardware%.rc read ?
- Where are the services started - meaning zygote,
  /system/bin/servicemanager etc

An example of an init.%hardware%.rc would be appreciated.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to track which of various possibilities in source end up on a runnable build.  I believe recent Android releases now have a working `grep` with the -R recursive flag, so I might be tempted to use that on an emulator to figure out where these things are in that particular example.  It would be harder on a device since so much is locked down now even against reading, but on the emulator the adb shell runs as root.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I am mainly interested in a general walkthrough of the boot process, not in any particular device's very precise boot details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok got it - both questions are answered in init.rc.

- hardware specific `init.%hardware%.rc` read at http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/system/core/rootdir/init.rc#8, where we see the line

  ```
  import /init.${ro.hardware}.rc
  ```

  Now, `ro.hardware` is read from the command line ([main](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/system/core/init/init.c#1013), [process_kernel_cmdline](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/system/core/init/init.c#process_kernel_cmdline) and finally [export_kernel_boot_props](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/system/core/init/init.c#756)). Where is the command line, well...
- Services started: in main the boot action is [triggered](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/system/core/init/init.c#1072), which contains the [lines](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/system/core/rootdir/init.rc#377)

  ```
  class_start core
  class_start main
  ```

  that start all the core and main services. Got the info from [Where are the Android system services started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041794/where-are-the-android-system-services-started/20060853#20060853)

NB: I refer to KitKat - YMMV